# slow write speed to Direct Connect storage

Tags: windows, storage, direct-attached-storage

Heres my situation.  I am running an IBM X3550 m4 with dual e5-2670 and 80 gigs of ram.  I have a ds4243 netapp appliances with 3gbps controllers and 24 x 2tb enterprise drives connect via qsfp to sas to an LSI 9207-8e sas 6gbps controller card and im using Windows Server 2016 and ntfs file format. I am using basic driver installed by windows for the sas card.

I have a bottleneck somewhere that is causing me to get 50 to 90mbps (90 if im lucky) write times.  I have several different drives but specs claim they are all 150mbps or higher.  Im running constant write processes to a single drive at a time.  I am setting them up as individual volumes and not using any type of raid configuration.  Also, I have already enabled write caching on the disks.

fwiw I was previously doing this process on linux and was getting better times.  My process was taking 4.8 to 5.2 hours and right now under windows its taking about 6.8ish.  I am processing a lot of drives so this extra time is really adding up. Any Ideas would be really appreciated.  Thanks in advance

p.s. I realize using netapp disk shelves without a netapp controller is unconventional but it does work, I have proven this. Please no comments on this. Until I have exhausted setup/configuration/optimization I won't consider (you cant do that) as a viable answer.

Comment: Why aren't you using the vendor supplied driver?

Comment: mainly because there isnt a listed driver for server 2016